# R pass a string containing backslashes from a file to charToRaw without escaping

Tags: r, excel, escaping, key, password-protection

I'm trying to read a key for a database into R from a password-protected file and convert it to raw, as follows:

Supposing my key is `\xb@\xErd\xD5b\x1bs`. My goal is to obtain the same raw key as I get when passing the key as a character string directly to the `charToRaw` function:

```
rawkey1 <- charToRaw("\xb@\xErd\xD5b\x1bs")

> rawkey1
[1] 0b 40 0e 72 64 d5 62 1b 73
```

I can save this in a .csv file and read it back in to R:

```
savemykey <- data.table(keyinbytes = "\xb@\xErd\xD5b\x1bs")

write.csv(savemykey, file = "My_key.csv")

mykey <- read.csv("My_key.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I can then convert this to raw and it produces the desired result:

```
> rawkey2 = charToRaw(mykey$keyinbytes)
> rawkey2
[1] 0b 40 0e 72 64 d5 62 1b 73
```

The raw keys produced from directly passing to the `charToRaw` function and from reading in the csv file containing the key are identical:

```
> rawkey1 == rawkey2
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

So far so good.  The only problem is that the key is a key to a database containing sensitive information, so I want to store it in a password-protected file.

The only way I could think of doing this was with Microsoft Excel (reading back in with the excel.link package and providing the password as an argument); however it seems that in creating the .xlsx file the backslashes are interpreted as escapes when they are read back in.  This results in an incorrect conversion from character to raw:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx2(savemykey, file = "My_key.xlsx", append = FALSE)
```

Then I open the Microsoft Excel file, assign the password "mypassword", save it and read it back in with the excel.link package:

```
library(excel.link)
mykey <- xl.read.file("My_key.xlsx", xl.sheet = 1, password = "mypassword")

# Re-running the conversion:
rawkey3 = charToRaw(mykey$keyinbytes)

> rawkey3
[1] 3f 40 3f 72 64 d5 62 3f 73
```

If I compare this result with the first key, it doesn't match:

```
> rawkey3 == rawkey1
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

This is because when reading in the Microsoft Excel file, R has interpreted the backslashes as escapes, escaping the characters following them and replacing them with a '?', see below:

```
# Key as assigned object in R:
> savemykey$keyinbytes
[1] "\v@\016rdÕb\033s"

# Key read in from Microsoft Excel file:
> mykey$keyinbytes
[1] "?@?rdÕb?s"
```

Based on what I've tried so far, it seems that if I save the key in any file type that can be saved as plain text (.csv, .txt, or directly in an R script and source it), the key is read back into R with the correct evaluation of the backslashes and converts to the correct pattern of raw bytes.  However, I have been unable to find any methods for password-protecting plain text files / .csv or R scripts.

I would like to either:

- find a way of password-protecting plain text format files that would preserve evaluation of the backslashes in the key when read back into R and for which the read in method takes a password as an argument, or;
- find a way to read in the key from a password protected Microsoft Excel file without the backslashes being escaped.

Any ideas on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm using (64-bit) R 3.3.2 with RStudio 1.0.136 in a windows 7 OS.  I think my Microsoft Office programs may be 32-bit as I have to call 32-bit R when querying MS Access databases (in case of any relevance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a way to create encrypted text files (which can be data or presumably an R script with a little modification). A script to create an encrypted file and then decrypt it after reading it back in using the digest package has been created by Stephane Doyen here: https://github.com/sdoyen/r_password_crypt .

This works as follows:

```
# Load libraries

# This does the encryption and decryption
require(digest) 

# This allows users to enter a password securely with a masked widget
require(getPass)

# I'll put the details I want to encrypt into a data.table
require(data.table)
```

Create and enter a password (length must be in multiples of 16 alpha-numeric characters e.g. 'myfavouritepw123'):

```
mypw <- charToRaw(getPass("Enter the password for your login details file:"))
```

Load Stephane's write.aes and read.aes functions:

```
# To encrypt and password protect a file:
write.aes <- function(df,filename, key) {
  require(digest)
  zz <- textConnection("out","w")
  write.csv(df,zz, row.names=F)
  close(zz)
  out <- paste(out,collapse="\n")
  raw <- charToRaw(out)
  raw <- c(raw,as.raw(rep(0,16-length(raw)%%16)))
  aes <- AES(key,mode="ECB")
  aes$encrypt(raw)
  writeBin(aes$encrypt(raw),filename)  
}


# To decrypt the file with a password after reading it back in:
read.aes <- function(filename,key) {
  require(digest)
  dat <- readBin(filename,"raw",n=1000)
  aes <- AES(key,mode="ECB")
  raw <- aes$decrypt(dat, raw=TRUE)
  txt <- rawToChar(raw[raw>0])
  read.csv(text=txt, stringsAsFactors = F)
}
```

Create the file that you want to encrypt:

Note: encryption with `write.aes` will result in '\' and the characters preceding them being misinterpreted. To avoid this convert the key to raw and save the raw bytes as a single character string. Use `paste0` and `collapse` to paste the characters representing each byte together (`sep` will not work).

```
mysecretlogin1 <- data.table(keyinbytes = paste0(charToRaw("\xb@\xErd\xD5b\x1bs"), collapse = " "))
```

Write the data.table to an encrypted file with write.aes using the password you created earlier as the key:

```
write.aes(df = mysecretlogin1, filename = "mysecretkey.txt", key = mypw)
```

Read the file back in and decrypt it with your password:

```
mypw <- charToRaw(getPass("Enter the password for your login details file:"))

mysecretlogin2 <- data.table(read.aes(filename = "mysecretkey.txt", key = mypw))
```

Check if the exported and imported files are the same:

```
    > mysecretlogin1 == mysecretlogin2
     keyinbytes
[1,]       TRUE
```

To use the key in its raw form, the character string can be converted back into raw bytes with this function (adding "0x" before each byte allows them to be passed to a list without quotes as a raw vector):

```
makeraw <- function(characterstring) {
  mystring <- strsplit(characterstring, " ")
  mystring <- lapply(mystring, function(x) paste0("0x", x))
  mystring <- as.raw(unlist(mystring))
  mystring
}
```

Apply the function:

```
myrawkey <- makeraw(mysecretlogin2$keyinbytes)
```

Check it has worked:

```
> myrawkey
[1] 0b 40 0e 72 64 d5 62 1b 73
> str(myrawkey)
 raw [1:9] 0b 40 0e 72 ...
> is.raw(myrawkey)
[1] TRUE
```

The 'key' (no pun intended!) in this solution is avoiding the whole issue of misinterpreting backslashes as escape characters by storing the key as a string version of (nice alpha numeric) raw bytes instead.